# How to block if JS download is not completed

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am downloading the JS file asynchronously by appending the JS file to HTML head.
Now in html body, before using the JS file, I want to check if JS file has downloaded and is present in the cache.
If the JS file is NOT present in the cache(e.g: in case of slow internet connnections), I want to block until it is downloaded.
In other words, if JS download is not complete, i want to simulate the behavior as in the case of blocking JS download.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

you can instantiate any object in JS file and in the HTML file you can check if that object is available using typeOf operator so if typeof(x) is undefined you can assume that file is not yet downloaded

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the HTMl file and the JS file: define a "callback" function somewhere in the already-loaded code, and call it from the end of your JS file. Example function:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
    function notify_file_is_loaded(identifier) {
      if (identifier === 'somefile.js') {
        // it's loaded!
        // run the code that (in synchronous mode) you'd block for 
      }
    }
  </script>
<!--- ... --->
```

and the JS file:

```
// somefile.js
// some JS code goes here
// ...snip...
notify_file_is_loaded('somefile.js');
```

Comment: Even if I am able to find out that JS is not ready, how can I wait for it to be downloaded. If I don't block, i will get JS error.

Comment: The way I am solving this case is by triggering the asynchronous download in the head and just before using that JS, i try to download the JS file synchronously using <script></script> tags. If the first JS download has already completed, the 2nd download picks up the Js from cache, otherwise it downloads in a blocking manner. The javascript file has no self-executable code, so no objects are instantiated twice

Answer (score 0):

Get the JS synchronously instead. Just append a script tag to `html > head` with `src="<script-location>"` and the browser will do this download synchronously.

going on a tanget here:
It is poor user-experience to block until something has downloaded. If you write your code using principles of graceful degradation, your page should only activate functionality that is available. Would you let another web-developer subject you to this. No I wouldn't - I would close that tab and move on :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you deferring the loading of the JavaScript file via JavaScript? If so you should be able to use the `onload` event handler to execute your code after the JavaScript file has been loaded:

```
<script>
    var js = document.createElement('script');
    js.onload = function() {
        // your code goes in here
    }
    js.src = 'foo.js';
    document.body.appendChild(js);

</script>
```

Comment: I am appending the JS to head very early in my code. This triggers async download of JS very early. This is a very large JS file which takes a lot of time to download & many features on my website uses this JS file. Now before any feature uses this JS file, I need to make sure that the JS is available. One option is to wrap code which uses this JS under a check to test if the JS is ready, but the code which uses this JS is scattered. I am looking for a solution where before using the JS, I can check if JS is available. If JS is not available, I want to block the rendering to avoid JS errors.